# スクリプト関数が見つかりませんでしたと表示されてしまう

Tags: google-apps-script

JavaScriptをほんの少しかじっただけのプログラミング初心者です。
初めてGASを導入してみたのですが、作成したスクリプトをスプレッドシートで動かしてみたいなと思い、図形描画でボタンを作成し、そこに下記のスクリプトを割り当ててみたのですが、以下のメッセージが表示されてしまい機能しませんでした。

```
問題が発生しました
スクリプト関数 activeCell() が見つかりませんでした
```

色々解決方法を調べたのですが分からず、詰まっています。
解決方法を教えて頂ければ幸いです。

やってみたい事は、ボタンを押した時にアクティブなセルへ値だけを貼り付ける
というシンプルなものです。とりあえずアクティブなセル番地を取得するところから試してみよう…と思っていきなりつまづいてしまいました

以下のコードでは、アクティブなセルを取得するだけの簡単な内容です。

```
function activeCell(){
  const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const activeSheet = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet();
  const cell= activeSheet.getCurrentCell();

  console.log(cell);
}
```

Comment: ボタンにスクリプトを割り当て、ボタンをクリックした際に、`問題が発生しました スクリプト関数 activeCell() が見つかりませんでした`のエラーが発生する場合は、おそらく、関数名として`activeCell()`をセットしているのではないかと推測します。関数名に`()`を付けていると、そのようなエラーが発生してしまいます。この場合、`()`は付けずに関数名`activeCell`をセットして再度テストしてみてください。